# Fast Expanding with Zerg

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

I understang the Fast Expand concept and have employed it.  However, I find myself to nervous to FE and end up doing 1 base.  The problem is that I get stuck in one base and to focused on offense, neglecting to expand out.  I feel if I had a better idea of when to expand, this would fix my problem.

My question is, when you scout your opponent, what are you looking for that allows you to FE or raises flags that tells you to one base for awhile?  And if you one base, when is it best to expand?

Comment: i'm pretty sure you're required to yell kekekekekekekekekekekekkekekekekekekekekkekekekekke into your mic while doing so

Comment: it didn't come up in anyone's answers, but a good time to expand is when you have map control.  Any time you feel like you have him bottled, feel free to throw down a 3rd or 4th expo

Comment: The answers to this question are interesting, because the Starcraft 2 meta-game has evolved. It's now considered very safe for Zerg to build a Hatchery first against Terran; with good control a Zerg can defeat a double proxy Barracks bunker rush.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you see your opponent expanding, you know it's safe to expand.  He's spending minerals to expand, which will delay his attack and give you time to get up defenses for your expansion if necessary.

If you see the makings of an aggressive build (early spawning pool or multiple barracks/gateways), you may want to hold back on your expansion until you see exactly what he's doing.  A fast attack will beat a fast expand every time.

If you see your opponent building to turtle, then expanding is your best option.  He will be stuck in his base and is essentially giving you free reign over the rest of the map.  The best way to defeat a turtler is through macro.

Comment: +1 for the third paragraph (which I was going to answer before seeing yours)

Comment: +1 I would probably write a longer answer which would say the exact same thing

Comment: Notice that this answer implicitly assumes you will be scouting what your opponent is doing, which is the most important part of knowing when to FE or not.

Comment: If you see your opponent building his expansion, you should go attack it. Start your own expansion just before you leave to attack.

Answer (score 4):

One factor not mentioned yet is map size, or more accurately, rush distance. How long does it take to reach your base from theirs?  The shorter the distance, the more you need to be concerned about a rush, as you will have less time to prepare.  This is related to map size, but is also affected by the layout.  some small maps can have a pretty long rush distance, while a bigger map with no terrain could allow a rush to run straight from one base to another.  if you scout a bunch of units leaving their base on a short rush distance map, you won't have time to throw down spine crawlers or pump units instead of drones.  On a long rush distance map, you can start pumping units when they push out, and have a small army when they finally arrive.

Comment: +1, I rely on the map much more than scouting for judging if I can FE safely.

Answer (score -1):

Whatever you do as zerg, you WILL need a second hatchery. I usually go for the second hatch as soon as I don't have any larvas left and have 300 minerals left.

The key to fast expansion is scouting. You need to be sure that you will be able to survive an attack by your opponent. When hes building units, build units. When hes building structures, its safe to expand

Comment: I'd say this is false.  There is plenty of one base Zerg play which can be decisive: ie. One base Muta, One base Roach

Comment: staying on top of your queen spawning more larva is key to a one base zerg play, you can have enough larva with one base that way.  On bigger maps its not always the best strategy if you are up against a strong opponent.  Eventually a weak economy will catch up to you.  Also, fast expand doesn't mean you have to go right for minerals.  Gas is usually the hold up so its usually a good idea to get mining on gas before minerals when you do expand.

Answer (score -5):

You don't absolutely need to know what your opponent is doing, all this emphasis on early scouting, etc, is sensible but too 'safe'.

For instance Jaedong (best zerg in the world) frequently fast expands without scouting, or even, gasps, 3 hatch before pool.

IM humble opinion in the current stage of your evolution as a player, you should practice with always fast expanding (choose bigger maps), regardless of scouting. You'll probably find yourself in a large economic advantage in 70% of your games. Because seriously, if a zerg only expands when he sees a terran expanding, THAT IS TOO LATE.

Edit:
I wrote some pretty ranty comments that everyone should check out. In conclusion, people should listen to those who actually play the game at a high level rather than pay attention to the vote counts. Because in the end... an aggregate silver league opinion... is still a silver league opinion.

Edit2:
You can see on the TL wiki that FE counters 1 base play.

http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/14_pool_15_hatch

Edit3:

Two years later I think I'm obviously right.

Comment: Jaedong plays StarCraft 1.  Some things might carry over, but the games' balance are completely different.

Comment: The standard zerg 14 pool 16 hatch FE is very very safe, and can hold off the vast majority of early game pushes (like 4 gate) as well as rushes (quick marine pressure) very easily. Unless we're talking about something like a very very aggressive cheese, in which case yes you should expend your energy staying alive rather than expanding yes...

Comment: Often a zerg player seeing his opponent fast expand will double-expand so as not to remain behind.  The points in my post are still valid.

Comment: @StrixVaria Just because you can double expand doesn't mean you should delay your first expansion. FE without scouting is standard play. *[edited by Oak]*

Comment: @Ben FE without scouting is most certainly not standard play.  Let's look at Idra (who popularized the 14 pool 15 hatch).  He consistently scouts on 12-13.  What's more in a 2 Gate situation he'll often sacrifice the expo as a delaying tactic.  What's more a late expand for Zerg isn't as detrimental as you make it considering drone production is more rapid than probe or SCV.  Try to remember builds like 2 Gate and 40 pop Marine push, are designed to counter FE, so its worth checking that out first.

Comment: @tzenes I'm not saying you shouldn't scout, but Idra does not hinge his expo timing on the opponent scouting. He also FEs without being able to scout the opponent rax or gate count, because FE is standard play. You say that he sacrifices the expo against a very aggressive early push, that's right. But he built it in the first place so it's there to give him larvae. You also can't compare drone production to probe or SCV, that's meaningless in StarCraft because of how different the races are. The only meaningful metric is the opportunity cost of not FEing, which is significant.

Comment: I agree that 16 hatch is fairly safe, but I still don't see any reason why you wouldn't scout your opponent. If you scout your opponent then you'll know whether or not it IS safe. If you see a 2 gate then you know that you shouldn't make the 2nd hatchery right away.

Comment: 14 hatch 14 pool and 14 pool 16 hatch are both fairly viable against everything but cheese all-in strats on quite a few maps. If you scout something aggressive...you just use your larva from your new hatch to make more lings. I actually haven't played 1v1's since the release, but in the beta I was doing just fine in diamond using 14 hatch 14 pool on larger maps, and 14 gas 14 pool on small maps. My scouting was solely to determine how much I could power drones on the larger maps.

Comment: @@tzenes and no... neither a 2 gate nor a 40 pop push counters FE. Sorry. I can explain more but the comments with the limited space and formatting... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UboKBbo0Qv0 I'll answer if you ask a question about it.

Comment: @Ben allow me to counter thus: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XSW0vy438_4 Two months later... with the exact same people... The truth is that Idra is an amazing Zerg player, and to show Idra coming back from a 2 Gate is like showing a video of Michael Jordan doing a through the legs dunk. It suffers from the problem that: most people aren't Michael Jordan.

Comment: @tzenes Tester is also amazingly good, why isn't he able to do damage with the 2 gate? Because the 2 gate doesn't counter 14/15, that's why. 14/15 is not some Idra only build as you seem to be implying, it's a very good build that's quite safe as a few people have attested to here. I would also like to hear you explain what you're demonstrating with your linked video.

Comment: I would also like to note that this answer was geared toward the specific asker of the question. Ben is recommending that at this stage of the player's development, he always fast expand in order to become more comfortable with that play style. This seems like a perfectly reasonable suggestion. While there are definitely unnecessary attacks and such in the comments, the core advice here is still very sound. As tzenes mentions, different skill levels have differing success in doing this, thus his best bet at finding an answer is to experiment with FE repeatedly.

Comment: @Ben I'm not saying 14pool/15hatch is Idra only.  I am saying that Idra is so good, that he could do a 15hatch/16pool and still survive a 2 Gate rush.  For us mere mortals, however, this is just not true a 2 Gate will stomp us.  Even in the KotB finals, Tester's 2 Gate did enough damage to Idra's early economy that Tester was able to out produce him for a victory.  I'm not saying 14 pool 15 hatch isn't a good build (its a great build), I'm saying that 2 Gate is strong against it (and even stronger against 15 hatch 16 pool).

Comment: @en1gmatic325 I don't think mindlessly trying builds is a good learning technique.  A better advice for learning would be to understand where the strengths and weaknesses in a strategy are, and once you understand that moving on from there.  If you keep trying builds over and over again, you will figure these things out eventually, but the end result is the same.

Comment: You can't equate the best build with the 'safest' build. Yes no doubt going roach would be the safest vs 2 gate, but if he built some cannons and expanded you would be behind. StarCraft is not rock paper scissors where BO1 always beats BO2 and you have to scout and figure out what BO the other guy is doing before you choose the 'counter' BO. That would make a completely dumb game. Standard BOs are standard because they're relatively safe against a wide array of openings. 14/15 falls in this category. Now  hatch first is extremely unsafe.

Comment: @tzenes Nothing I suggested said to do it mindlessly. How do you propose to understand the strengths and weaknesses without trying it? Until you have a build down smoothly it plays very differently and is viable against a much smaller realm of opposing strategies. Given that zerg FE is viable against probably some 90% of builds on larger maps, why not just try it? I've always found I improve with a BO much faster if I try it out some and then read up on it rather than the other way around. I doubt I'm the only one for whom this is true.

Comment: @ben I agree that it's a great build certainly I use it, but the question wasn't "what is the best zerg build" it was asking for the strengths and weaknesses. Saying always do it isn't a very good answer (even I if it does meet his phrasing). I agree that no strat is a guarantee of victory, which is why knowing the strengths and weaknesses is so important.